# Job still running even when deleting nodes

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I created a two nodes clusters and I created a new job using the busybox image that sleeps for 300 secs. I checked on which node this job is running using

`kubectl get pods -o wide`

I deleted the node but surprisingly the job was still finishing to run on the same node. Any idea if this is a normal behavior? If not how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Jobs aren't scheduled or running on nodes. The role of a job is just to define a policy by making sure that a pod with certain specifications exists and ensure that it runs till the completion of the task whether it completed successfully or not.

When you create a job, you are declaring a policy that the built-in `job-controller` will see and will create a pod for. Then the built-in `kube-scheduler` will see this pod without a node and patch the pod to it with a node's identity. The `kubelet` will see a pod with a node matching it's own identity and hence a container will be started. As the container will be still running, the `control-plane` will know that the node and the pod still exist.

There are two ways of breaking a node, one with a drain and the second without a drain. The process of breaking a node without draining is identical to a network cut or a server crash. The api-server will keep the node resource for a while, but it 'll cease being Ready. The pods will be then terminated slowly. However, when you drain a node, it looks as if you are preventing new pods from scheduling on to the node and deleting the pods using `kubectl delete pod`.

In both ways, the pods will be deleted and you will be having a job that hasn't run to completion and doesn't have a pod, therefore `job-controller` will make a new pod for the job and the job's `failed-attempts` will be increased by 1, and the loop will start over again.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this highly detailed flow, really useful